# cloud carousel slide, need click view detail on only picture on the front

Tags: jquery, cloud, carousel, slide

I have the  cloud carousel slide  fo my first webpage to show 10 picture, When I click next image is look ok, my problem is I want only the front image can click for more detail information the rest I not need, the image that show in the front position can view more detail.

/************ Jquery Code ********************/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
            if($("#carousel .objects").length) {               
                    $("#carousel .goprev, #carousel .gonext").click(function(){
                            return false;
                    });

                    var xPos = $("#carousel .objects").width() / 2;
                    var yPos = $("#carousel .objects").height() / 4;        //8;

                    // This initialises carousels on the container elements specified, in this case, carousel1.
                    $("#carousel .objects").CloudCarousel({         
                            reflHeight: 25,         //30,//56,
                            reflOpacity: 0.2,
                            reflGap: $.browser.msie || $.browser.safari ? 0 : 1,    //2,
                            //xRadius: $("#carousel .objects").width() * 0.48,
                            yRadius:-60,    //-25,//0.1,//40,
                            xPos: xPos,     //128,
                            yPos: yPos,     //32,
                            minScale:-0.1,          //0.4,
                            FPS:30,
                            speed: $.browser.msie || $.browser.safari ? 0.2 : 0.05,         //0.2,
                            //mouseWheel:true,
                            bringToFront:true,

                            autoRotate: 'left',
                            autoRotateDelay: 6000,          //5000,

                            buttonLeft: $("#carousel .goprev"),
                            buttonRight: $("#carousel .gonext"),
                            altBox: $("#carousel .mid .padding"),
                            titleBox: $("#carousel .title"),
                            nameBox: $("#carousel h1")
                    });
            }
    });
```

/***************** PHP Code *************/

```
    $html .= "<a href='"._URL_."property/{$p->pdId}/".strtolower(str_replace(array(" ","/"),"-",$alt)).".html' onclick='return false';'>
                <img src='"._URL_."upload_pictures/{$image->imPhysicalPath}' class='cloudcarousel' width='407' height='242' alt='$siteDescription' title='$price' name='$alt' />
            </a>";
            // {$p->pdTitle}
    }
    return $html;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could add the following code to your cloud-carousel.js file

```
$(container).on('click', 'a', function(event){

    if($(this).index()!=$(container).data('cloudcarousel').frontIndex){
        event.preventDefault();         
    }

});
```